# What alternative for get_remaining_time_in_millis in AWS Lambda is available for Google Cloud Function?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I need to exit my loop before the function gets timed out, for this in AWS Lambda we have get_remaining_time_in_millis which I generally use for this purpose.

```
do {
... // process the tasks in small batches that can be completed in, say, less than 10s
// when there's less than 10s left, stop
} while (context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() > 10000);
```

Is there a similar way to accomplish the same in GCP? I am trying to avoid a rest api call to fetch the function configuration and implement it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I don't think that Google Cloud Functions exposes such a value at the moment. If you really need something like that, you'd have to implement it yourself by recording the time your code first starts, and tracking that against the maximum run time you configured, which you can get by reading the `FUNCTION_TIMEOUT_SEC` environment variable.

It sounds like a reasonable feature though, so I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#reserved_keys_key_validation) says you can get the current function's timeout using environment variable FUNCTION_TIMEOUT_SEC. But as you say, you will have to compute the remaining time yourself if you want to avoid a timetout.

Comment: Thanks for that update Doug. That indeed means that the basic building blocks are there, you just have to put them together.